# jQuery: удалить все внутренние тэги, кроме одного указанного

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как можно с помощью `jQuery` удалить все тэги внутри контейнера, кроме одного указанного? Например, как можно удалить из тэга с классом `.container` всё, кроме `div.main`?

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="main">main</div>
    <div class="aside">aside</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
$('.container').children().not('.main').remove();
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="main">main</div>
    <div class="aside">aside</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

css вариант

```css
.container *:not(.main){
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="main">main</div>
    <div class="aside">aside</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Взял ваш сниппет для правок в вопросе и соседнем ответе. Спасибо :)